# How to add custom attributes to Windows Azure Active Directory User Account?

Tags: azure

I want to add custom attributes specific to user, say for example LeavePolicyId, in Windows Azure Active Directory User.

I tried different ways - using PowerShell CmdLets, using Azure WAAD Graph API, and obviously through Azure Managementment portal UI. But all efforts never gave me a solution.

I see present list of attributes available here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194096.aspx. But I want to add custom ones.

Please let me know if there is another way to solve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Custom attributes are a schema modification. The schema is a partition in itself, a kind of ldap directory of metadata. Do you have access to the schema partition ?

Comment: Thanks ixe013 for your comment. I have no clue on Schema partition. Can share some resource on it over web. I can give a read.

Comment: [Start here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961591.aspx#EDAA) for the big picture on partitions, and follow the [first link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961581.aspx) for more details. It's OK to post an answer to your own question when you found it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ExtendedProperty, add the property to an App register in AAD(Azure Active Directory) to an user, and then asing the value...

```
            ExtensionProperty identidadSecreta = new ExtensionProperty
            {
                Name = "LaIdentidadSecreta",
                DataType = "String",
                TargetObjects = { "User" }
            };

            myApplication.ExtensionProperties.Add(identidadSecreta);
            await myApplication.UpdateAsync();
            client.Context.SaveChanges();
```

Then to the user:

```
            User user = null;
        try
        {
            ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
            user = (User)await client.Users.GetByObjectId(objectId).ExecuteAsync();
            user.SetExtendedProperty("extension_e99c8a1afb544da491b098931b0a2ad8_LaidentidadSecreta", "Bruno Días");
            await user.UpdateAsync();
```

Geting the value:

```
                string extensionValue = (String)user.GetExtendedProperties()["extension_e99c8a1afb544da491b098931b0a2ad8_LaidentidadSecreta"];// The Guid is the App Guid.
```

Beaware of [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/issues/28) !!!. Fortunately if you initialize the                 ActiveDirectoryClient and use Microsoft.Data.Services.Client version 5.7.0 will work.

```
    //////
    private static void UndeclaredPropertyHandler(MessageWriterSettingsArgs args)
    {
        var field = args.Settings.GetType().GetField("settings",
          BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var settingsObject = field?.GetValue(args.Settings);
        var settings = settingsObject as ODataMessageWriterSettings;
        if (settings != null)
        {
            settings.UndeclaredPropertyBehaviorKinds =
               ODataUndeclaredPropertyBehaviorKinds.SupportUndeclaredValueProperty;
        }
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> SomeMethod(string objectId)
    {
        User user = null;
        try
        {
            // forma normal
            ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
            // #adicional
            client.Context
                  .Configurations.RequestPipeline
                  .OnMessageWriterSettingsCreated(UndeclaredPropertyHandler);
            // #adicional
```

Comment: "extension_e99c8a1afb544da491b098931b0a2ad8_LaidentidadSecreta" is the concat of "extension_"+app GUID +"property name"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a way to do this via the Graph API...it's not going to look much like extending the AD DS schema...but Azure AD doesn't look much like that anyway.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2013/06/24/extending-the-windows-azure-graph-using-the-windows-azure-graph-store.aspx

That article has more info...

Comment: That's ok. There's actually a preview program now for extensible schema...http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2014/03/06/extend-azure-active-directory-schema-using-graph-api-preview.aspx

Comment: // , This may be interesting, because not only does it describe how to update the schema for Active Directory User Objects, but, apparently, I can also update the schema for many other things in Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview